# Insert cakephp POST params into URL

Tags: url, cakephp, parameters

I have this form below which contains two checkboxes to sort some products:

```
<form id="FiltreExtraForm" action="" method="post" name="FiltreExtraForm">
    <input id="ProductsDeliveryPrice" type="checkbox" value="1" name="data[Products][delivery_price]"/>
    <input id="ProductsPicture" type="checkbox" value="1" name="data[Products][picture]"/>
</form>
```

After POST I do the filtering but I also want to add received parameters to URL E.g: /products/index/delivery_price:1/picture:0 . Is this possible. How can I do that?

Note: I don't want to use GET to send form info.

Comment: I hate to break it to you, but GET **is** the URL. The two are one and the same.

Comment: Yes. But I don't want to send form parameters in URL. I want to add them manually somewhere in controller to be able to format them as I want and to have them available for later use

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  If you just want the URL stuff, you can just post the variables, loop through them in the controller, and redirect to the GET url.  Or you could override the form submit button using javascript, and have your application logic in the js code.

I can't think of a situation where you'd want to do this instead of something else.  What's your use case for doing things like this?

Comment: GET is appended to the URL - it is not the URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you are looking to do a [Post/Redirect/Get](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).

Here are two examples of doing this in CakePHP:

- [Searching on surname](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/688016/how-can-i-get-a-wildcard-list-in-a-cakephp-scaffolding/688316#688316)
- [Searching on multiple fields](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/ChrisA9/2008/12/29/search-feature-as-an-sql-query-in-2-steps#comment4caea153-3044-4701-b9bd-490b82f0cb67)

The two main advantages of redirecting a `POST` to a `GET` request are:

1. Users don't get the "Do you want to resubmit?" dialog if they refresh
2. The resulting page/query can be bookmarked

Answer (score 0):

In the action to which you post, you could simply prepare the GET url and then redirect to this url. The action for that url then does the filtering.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly (and I'm not sure that I do), you can pass additional variables on the query string of the form's action quite easily. Conventionally, that might look like this:

```
<form id="FiltreExtraForm" action="/products/index?delivery_price=1&picture=0" method="post" name="FiltreExtraForm">
```

Using Cake, you should be able to do the same without the traditional query string if you'd rather (though the traditional method above will also work):

```
<form id="FiltreExtraForm" action="/products/index/delivery_price:1/picture:0" method="post" name="FiltreExtraForm">
```

I would recommend looking at the form helper or at least constructing the action URI using helpers, but this should get you what you're after.