# Cakephp: How to make form get variables show up as passed args?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I have an action called search on a controller called categories. `/categories/search`

I also have this route in place:

```
    Router::connect(
        '/search',
        array('controller'=>'categories','action'=>'search')
    );
```

So the URL is `/search` instead of `/categories/search`

I have a form set to `get` for that url:

```
$form->create(
    NULL,
    array(
        'type'=>'get',
        'url'=>array('controller'=>'categories','action'=>'search')
    )
);
```

This form contains 1 input field named `q` and when you submit it the URL you are taken to looks just like this:

> /search?q=your+search+terms

The problem is this would play much nicer with other parts of the application if it were a `passedArg` instead of a get var. So the URL would look like this:

> /search/q:your%20search%20terms

Is there anyway to set the form to post like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first, the router:

> ```
> Router::connect('/search', array('controller'=>'categories','action'=>'search'));
> Router::connect('/search/*', array('controller'=>'categories','action'=>'search'));
> ```

You can use redirect to have the pretty url:

> ```
> function search(){
>    if(!empty($this->params['url']['q'])){
>       $this->redirect(array('q'=>$this->params['url']['q']));
>    }else if(!empty($this->params['named']){
>       // search here
>    }
> }
> ```

Comment: +1 for [PRG](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1459845/insert-cakephp-post-params-into-url/1462494#1462494)

Comment: Thanks, this is the conclusion I was coming to myself as well.

Answer (score 0):

This will never work without a JS hack because named parameters are part of the URL.
The form's target url is static, and won't be modified by the contents of an input field.
You can do this with a JS hack though, but isn't very nice.

Comment: Yeah I don't want to use JS. The reason I want to do this is because the search results are paginated. When you click a page number, all the `passedArgs` are retained (whether they are used by the PaginationHelper or not) but GET vars are lost.