# CakePHP Gurus: how to redirect generic URL to language prefixed URL

Tags: cakephp, url-routing, redirect

I have language-prefixed URLs working great (`site.com/en/controller/action` and `site.com/fr/controller/action`, etc.), but if somebody enters a URL *without* the language, I want to redirect to a URL that has the language. So `site.com/controller/action` redirects to `site.com/xx/controller/action` where `xx` is a value specifying the language, that is stored in the session (or a cookie).

I suspect I can just look up the `language` index in the `$this->params` array, and simply redirect if I don't find it. Something like:

```
if (!isset($this->params['language']) {
    $this->redirect(array('controller' => $this->controller, 'action' => $this->action, 'language' => $this->Session->read('Config.language')));
}
```

But my concern is that this would drop any POST or GET data.

What am I missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I' not huge expert in this case but I have understood that it's good practise to always redirect POST data. So before checking language, do what you should do with POST data, and after that do a redirect with proper language in url.

Look this:
[Insert cakephp POST params into URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1459845/insert-cakephp-post-params-into-url)

You can also look this->params for GET data and pass that to $this->redirect to carry it on.

Comment: Agreed. You can always redirect your post and get data so don't worry about dropping it.