# CakePHP: Prevent GET form fields in URL

Tags: php, cakephp, get, form-helpers

I've got a CakePHP search form that has `'type'=>'get'`. Basically, one of the elements in the form is a submit button of type image. When the form is posted, in the URL I always get these x & y coordinates of the image submit button:

http://site.com/controller/action?**x=22&y=36**&query=hello

Is there any way I can prevent the coordinates from showing up in the URL? The reason is so that someone else could use the same URL to perform the same search, without that unintuitive stuff in the link.

Thanks!

Comment: Move the button out of the form, and stick javascript on it to trigger the submission of the form.

Comment: I'm getting these 'x' and 'y' coordinates when trying to access the $_POST variables also. I wanted my form to submit to an external form processor, which we use as a centralized location for clients to login and download CSV files with registrations. Wtf are they?

Comment: x and y coordinates are when you use an submit button of type image. Either ignore them, or change the submit button type to type="submit".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use some javascript on the button:

```
document.getElementById('myImageButton').onclick = function() {
    this.form.submit();
    return false;
};
```

Alternatively, in your controller in the `beforeFilter` function, you could check for the presence of the unwanted variables, strip them out and redirect to the nice URL. This does mean there'll be 2 HTTP requests made though.

Comment: Hmm, I was afraid of this HTTP request duplication. Well, I suppose it's the only solution left. Thanks!

Comment: did you try the javascript solution?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are looking to do a [Post/Redirect/Get](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).

Here are two examples of doing this in CakePHP:

- [Searching on surname](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/688016/how-can-i-get-a-wildcard-list-in-a-cakephp-scaffolding/688316#688316)
- [Searching on multiple fields](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/view/search-feature-as-an-sql-query-in-2-steps#comment-3302)

Advantages of redirecting a `POST` to a `GET` request are:

1. Users don't get the "Do you want to resubmit?" dialog if they refresh
2. The resulting page/query can be bookmarked
3. You can utilise CakePHP's built-in SEF routing, so instead of URLs with `/search?q=contact` you can get `/search/contact`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `submit` helper function, use `button` function and set button type to submit.

```
echo $this->Form->**button**($this->Html->image('header_search_icon.png'), array(**'type'=>'submit'**));
```